# why is my function not adding up all my numbers? it only gives the first number

Tags: python

I am currently a beginner in python,
why is my function not returning the  arguments  added
together?  here is my code:

```py
def add(*numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        total = total + number
        return(total)
```

I use the function as below.

```py
add(9,9,9)
```

I get the output.

```py
9
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1941241) and then add your code to your question as code, rather than an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stuck with loops in python - only returning first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118391/stuck-with-loops-in-python-only-returning-first-value)

Comment: Your `return` statement is indented too far, align it with the `for`.

Comment: **We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow.** Please post your code as ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) text. Read more [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Questions with images of text/code/errors are routinely closed. Please also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the question guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure this & your future questions are suitable for this Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with indentation.

Try this:

```
def add(*numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        total = total + number

    return (total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code returns total after one run of the add function, move the return(total) one tab backwards, for example, your code should look like:

```
def add(*numbers):
   total = 0
   for the number in number:
        total += number
   return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the indentation of the line `return(total)`. Right now it just returns the first number without ever looking at the others.

this should work:

```
def add(*numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        total+=number
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated in their answers, you have an intentation problem. Since there are no ; nor {}, Python is very sensitive to indentation to define the limits on functions... everything, really.

Try:

```
def add(*numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        total = total + number
    return (total)
```